# android fragment: recycle bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, fragment, recycle

I am using a `DialogFragment` from the compatibility package. I have a `Bitmap` which I need to recycle when the dialog closes, but when I call `findViewByID()` inside `onDestroyView()` it returns null. I have also tried keeping a reference to the view from `onCreateView()` but it is also null by the time `onDestroyView()` is called.

How can I recycle a bitmap in a `DialogFragment` when the fragment closes?

Answer (score 1):

onDestroyView() allows the fragment to clean up resources associated with its View, try to recycle bitmap in onDismiss or in other method that called before onDestroyView

Comment: onDestroy() and onCancel() return null. what other lifecycle methods can I try?

Comment: sorry I meant onDismiss and onCancel