# Recycle the bitmap in Fragment/Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, bitmap, android-activity

Hello I am trying to get `bitmap` from URL in the `Fragment`. I know programmer should recycle the `bitmap` to release the memory and avoid `OutOfMemoryException`.

So here I am very confused where I should call `recycle` method in `Fragment` and `Activity`, I see many answer but that didn't seems to me any nice answer like [android fragment: recycle bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329260/android-fragment-recycle-bitmap)

Can you please help me to clear my confusion.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call the recycle method in onDestroy() if you finish using it when the activity / fragment is destroyed. Otherwise recycle it as soon as you are finished using it